# Regular expression in negation

Tags: java, regex

I want this regex to yield just the string `acl`. How do I do that ? I keep getting `2013-` ,even though I have a negation operator    .

```
void testPattern()
     {
        Pattern pattern =
        Pattern.compile("^.*-");

        Matcher matcher =
        pattern.matcher("2013-acl");

        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            println matcher.group();

        }
      }
```

Comment: There is no negation operator in the above code...

Comment: where do you have a negation? ^ at the start means "start of line"

Comment: If you use `^` inside of `[]`, then it is a "negation operator", but used elsewhere without escaping it, `^` means beginning of line.

Comment: what do you actually need to do?  for all I know the regex `"acl"` will work

Comment: I don't know too much about regex, but why wouldn't you just use println "acl"?

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern `"^.*-"` matches the input only till the hyphen.

Change it to `"^.*-(.*)$"` and instead of `matcher.group()` use `matcher.group(1)`.

So with this modified pattern and using the same input:

1. `^` matches beginning of the input
2. First `.*` matches `2013`
3. `-` matches a `-`
4. Second `.*` matches `acl`
5. `$` matches the end of the input

Parentheses around second `.*` make a capturing group. The captured pattern becomes obtainable with `matcher.group(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution without a regex:

Use a `StringBuilder` to delete everything before the `-`.

```
String string1 = "2013-acl";
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(string1);
b.delete(0, defaultBrowser.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
string1 = b.toString();
System.out.println(string1);
```

That program should print out `acl`. No need for a regex.

### Solution if you *need* a regex:

```
String string1 = "2013-acl";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=-).*$").matcher(string1);
if (matcher.find()) System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

That program should print out `acl`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to get everything after the `-`: `(?<=-).*$`

However, as it has been pointed out... simply splitting on the `-` would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is the beginning of string operator not a negation operator.

If you want to match only the end I suggest using :

```
"-(\w+)"
```

(Don't forget to escape back slash in Java.)

Then retrieve what is matched in the `$1` variable.

You can do this using using the [Matcher.group()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) function.

```
Pattern pattern =
Pattern.compile("-(\\w+)");

Matcher matcher =
pattern.matcher("2013-acl");

matcher.find();
println matcher.group(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `acl` as the regex? or `acl$` if you only want it to match acl if it is at the end of the string